# What's an awesome formatter for MXML/AS3?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, mxml, flash-builder

I want a Flash Builder plugin that takes ugly unformatted mxml and makes it beautiful

[image]

+1 if you would like something like this also.

Edit: noticed that screenshot is barely legible. Larger version here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/672147/mxmlFormatterDream.png

Comment: I once loaded the messy mxml file (bad indentation) into an swf through a URLLoader, created an XML object with it and called `trace(xml.toXMLString());` Won't work for spacing between attributes though.

Comment: The standard is to do a stack, not stretch them out horizontally like your example under pretty-ness. Flex Formatter (mentioned and linked below) has options for doing that. IDEs like FDT and IntelliJ IDEA have powerful formatters (for Flex) built in.

Comment: I agree, Joel. I'm blessed with a 27" monitor so for me it's great to stretch out the tags, but I forget that most people don't have as much width real estate ass I do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give the [Flex Formatter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/flexformatter/) plugin a shot, only one I know of.  Not sure if it'll do that exact formatting you have there but it has a lot of options.